Use virtual scroll in Angular CDK table
I use Angular CDK table(ver. 15) to build a large table.
I want to improve the preformance by using cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport.
how can i combain the *cdkRowDef of CDK table with *cdkVirtualFor of CDK scrolling?
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport appendOnly itemSize="50" class="example-viewport">

<table cdk-table recycleRows [dataSource]="dataSource" [trackBy]="identifyRows" class="table-with-tree-wrapper">
   ...
   ...
   ...
    <tr cdk-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr
        cdk-row
        *cdkRowDef ="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
        [class.table-row-hover]="hoverOnRow"
        [class.table-row-selected]="row?.element?.selected"></tr>
</table>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>

I tried to use cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport without cdkVirtualFor but it didn't work.
